# Symbolizing Layers from a PostGIS Database to many Client Computers

Tags: postgis, symbology

I was hoping someone could help with a symbolizing issue.  I have a PostGIS database on a server with a number of layers.  The layers of a series of polygons, lines and points that all share the same symbology.  I want to symbolize the layers with the same symbol schema on computers in lab that are connected to the database.  I have used the MultiQML tool to symbolize the layers and saved them on the server, which did not load the correct symboled features on the connected lab computers.  Do I have to have the QML files on each lab computer, or is the a way to have a QML file on the server that each lab computer will be able to read via the database connection and symbolize the layers correctly without needing to store the QML locally?

Thanks,
Ryan

Comment: So you are using QGIS Server?